# how to highlight selected item in recyclerview?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-cardview, foreground

I am new to Material Card view and I want to change the card Foreground color programmatically when it is long pressed.
But the parameter to the setCardForegroundColor() method requires an instance of ColorStateList to be passed and I dont know how to create ColorStateList instance for my needs.

So can anyone please tell me how to use the ColorStateList to highlight cardview when it is long pressed ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far If you stuck with a particular bug add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the ColorStateList, to change colors of my RecyclerView items when they are pressed I use a `drawable` item in the `background` of the list item. Here's how I implement it:

List item example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <!-- Above: android:background defines the list item Touch Selector to highlight row -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating_name_textview"
        style="@style/EditorFieldStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorStatListItemText"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating_score_textview"
        style="@style/EditorFieldStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textColor="@color/colorStatListItemText"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="100" />

</LinearLayout>
```

List item selector example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Adding Touch Selectors for when items in the RecyclerView are touched -->
    <!-- Three states: pressed, activated, and selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryLight" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryLight" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryLight" android:state_selected="true" />

    <!-- Define background color for Touch Selectors when item is not selected (light gray) -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorBackgroundLight" />

</selector>
```

The list item references the list item selector and highlights the RecyclerView item appropriately, based on the colors I've defined in the color value file.